# How to write custom graph algorithms in arangodb, this must run internally?

Tags: graph, arangodb, arangojs, arangodb-foxx

I am trying to implement few graph algorithms in arangodb other than the ones available in the pregel (PageRank, HITS, etc), for example like the floyd-warshall, girman-newman, etc. But since it is not available i want to write and run this internally for example with AQL language itself, but this would be complex, at the same time I dont want to use drivers of other languages since i want the performance of this algorithm to depend only on the internal process of ArangoDB.

I tried to use only existing pregel algorithm for now, I was wondering if using foxx service would be a solution. But it would be nice if I can get any other solutions.